# Extracting only numeric parts of a string column with apply and sub breaks

Tags: r

I have a data frame `dat` in R, which looks like that:

```
id  x   y                           z
1   0   4 California                15 MSG 2017/11
2   0   1 Nationally Representative 11 MSG 2016/04
3   1   1 Nationally Representative 8 MSG 2016/01
4   0   1 Nationally Representative 1 ASDE 2014/01
5   2   1 Nationally Representative 8 MSG 2016/01
6   0   1 Nationally Representative 5 MSG 2015/07
```

Now I want to loop through each column and only keep the numeric part at the beginning, e.g. in first row, variable x, I want to keep the "4", variable z I want to keep the "15" and so on.

I tried the following (i.e. searching with space characters in each column and delete it + the part after the space):

```
dat_new = apply(dat, 2, function(x) sub(" .+", "", x)) # searchs for any space and deletes the space + everything after the space
dat_new = as.data.frame(apply(dat_new, 2, as.numeric))
```

However, what works for a small subset of the data, e.g., the first six rows, eventually breaks. I.e., my total data frame hast 5100 rows and applying above functions leads to the first column ("id") getting empty, this also happens to some other columns. I currently found a workaround with using an actual for-loop, **but wanted to nonetheless check what's wrong with my code and if there's another elegant solution.**

Data types of `dat` are:

```
'data.frame':   5109 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x : int  0 0 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ y : Factor w/ 4 levels "1 Nationally Representative",..: 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 3 ...
 $ z : Factor w/ 16 levels "1 ASDE 2014",..: 7 3 15 1 15 12 12 8 13 5 ...
```

Comment: Why not use `grep` or related functions? Also please share data with `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr` on the columns 'y', 'z' to extract the first set of numeric substring

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
dat %>%
      mutate_at(vars(y:z), list(~ parse_number(as.character(.))))
#  d x y  z
#1 1 0 4 15
#2 2 0 1 11
#3 3 1 1  8
#4 4 0 1  1
#5 5 2 1  8
#6 6 0 1  5
```

Or another option is to remove the substring from the space and then convert to `numeric`

```
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(y:z), list(~ as.numeric(str_remove(., "\\s+.*"))))
```

---

Or using `base R`, we remove the space followed by other characters and convert to numeric for columns other than the first

```
dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1], function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\s+.*", "", x)))
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(d = 1:6, x = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L), y = structure(c(2L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1 Nationally Representative", 
 "4 California"), class = "factor"), z = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 
 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1 ASDE 2014/01", "11 MSG 2016/04", "15 MSG 2017/11", 
  "5 MSG 2015/07", "8 MSG 2016/01"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
  -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this option. Quick question, in your example, you specifically selected columns "y" and "z", however, in reality, I have hundreds of columns and can't preset. So I like to loop through all columns and kind of ignore all columns where no string replacement is necessary.

Comment: @deschen  If the columns are in sequence, you can use `colnm1:colnm100` etc or `1:100` (numeric index).  Do you have it in sequence

Comment: @deschen If the columns to be identified always should start with number, then create the index with `i1 <- sapply(dat, function(x) any(grepl("^\\d+",x ) ))` and use that index for looping

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these approaches work in my example (if I want to automatically loop through my columns). I checked the regex parts here: https://regexr.com/4c1bl and weirdly enough, only the the `sub(" .+", "", x)` replacement really matches. I now used a combination of this expression + your solution for identifying columns (with some adjustment of code), where I excluded rows that are already numeric or integer: `i <- sapply(dat, function(x) any(is.numeric(x), is.integer(x)))` and then `dat_new[, i==F] = as.data.frame(apply(dat_new[,i==F], 2, function(x) sub(" .+", "", x)))`

Comment: @deschen may be there is some pattern difference in your example

Answer (score 1):

Using base R we can `lapply` over selected columns and extract the numeric part

```
cols <- c("y", "z")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.numeric(sub("(^\\d+).*", "\\1", x)))

df
#  id x y  z
#1  1 0 4 15
#2  2 0 1 11
#3  3 1 1  8
#4  4 0 1  1
#5  5 2 1  8
#6  6 0 1  5
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this option. Same question as for akrun's solution: in your example, you specifically selected columns "y" and "z", however, in reality, I have hundreds of columns and can't preset. So I like to loop through all columns and kind of ignore all columns where no string replacement is necessary.

Comment: @deschen you can also select column by number. So if you want to apply it for for column 10 to 100, you could make cols as `cols <- 10:100` and then use `lapply`.

Comment: Sure, that would work. But that requires me to know in advance which columns need replacement. In reality, you often have messy data. E.g. in this exmaple, it's from a survey with 500 or so columns and some/many of them have this weird number + text combination. SO I was looking for an elegant way to just do it in one rush. Of course, I could also check before which columns are already of type integer or numeric and exclude them from the replacement, but might be there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

An `apply` implementation(might be slow):

```
as.data.frame(apply(dat,2,function(x) gsub("[A-Z].*","",x)))
  d x  y   z
1 1 0 4  15 
2 2 0 1  11 
3 3 1 1   8 
4 4 0 1   1 
5 5 2 1   8 
6 6 0 1   5
```

Comment: Good approach as well